# Spring batch issue in using multiple datasource facing IllegalStateException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction: Already value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-batch, multiple-databases

I am trying to use multiple datasource in spring batch where first step connects to one database (`sybase`) and second step connects to differnt datasoruce (`posgres`) but I am getting below error when ever I try to run the same :

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@713a4f8d] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@25a51f53] bound to thread [http-nio-9093-exec-1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:448)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
..
..
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@713a4f8d] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@25a51f53] bound to thread [http-nio-9093-exec-1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:193)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:423)
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.**.dao.posgres",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "positionEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "positionTransactionManager"
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class PosgresdbConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Qualifier("positionEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean positionEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(positionDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[] { "com.**.dao.posgres" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Qualifier("positionDataSource")
    public DataSource positionDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(
                env.getProperty("datasource.posgres.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("datasource.posgres.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("datasource.posgres.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("datasource.posgres.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Qualifier("positionTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager positionTransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                positionEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}



@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.**.dao.Sybase",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "SybaseEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "SybaseTransactionManager"
)
public class SybasedbConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean SybaseEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(sybaseDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[] { "com.**.Sybase" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource sybaseDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(
                env.getProperty("datasource.posgres.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager SybaseTransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                SybaseEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

**BATCH CONFIG**

```
    @Bean
    public Step loadPositionData(final ItemReader<PositionDataResult> positionDataReader,
                                 final ItemProcessor<Object, PositionDataResult> positionRecordProcessor,
                                 final ItemWriter<Object> positionFileWriter) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("position-load-account")
                .<LoadPositionForRiskSP, LoadPositionForRiskSP>chunk(2000)
                .reader(positionDataReader)
                .processor(positionRecordProcessor)
                .writer(positionFileWriter)
                .listener(new NoDataFoundListener())
                .transactionManager(positionTransactionManager)
                .build();

    }
```

Using first datasource works fine in first step reader:

```
    @Transactional(value="SybaseTransactionManager", propagation= Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED, isolation= Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED,readOnly = true)
    public PositionDataResult loadDataFromSP() {}
```

Now using secondary datasource in second step gives error:

```
    @Transactional(transactionManager="positionTransactionManager", readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void write(List<? extends Object> list) throws Exception {}
```

Comment: can you check this project https://github.com/snicoll/demo-multi-entity-managers

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to making the `ItemWriter#write` method transactional here:

```
@Transactional(transactionManager="positionTransactionManager", readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void write(List<? extends Object> list) throws Exception {}
```

The item writer will be called in a transaction driven by Spring Batch, so this annotation is not needed and should be removed. Same thing for the reader as well. The transaction manager and the transaction attributes of the step should defined using the methods on the `StepBuilder`.

If the step involves multiple transactional resources, then a `JtaTransactionManager` should be used to coordinate the transactions between those resources.